# In Rails 5, how do I write a finder "OR" query to say exlucde from a list or be nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, where-clause, finder

I want to write a Rails 5 finder query that returns objects if a field does not belong to a certain set of values or is null.  I tried the below

```
Order
.joins(...joins1...)
.joins(...joins2...)
.left_outer_joins(:customer => :program)
      .where.not(
        :programs => { :number => excluded_numbers }
      ).or(:programs => { :number => nil})
    .where(...)
```

but this results in a

```
ArgumentError: You have passed Hash object to #or. Pass an ActiveRecord::Relation object instead.
```

What is the proper way to form my "OR" clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you must pass an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, right now you're passing the `{ :programs => { :number => nil} }` hash.

Try with:

```
orders = Order.joins(...).joins(...).left_outer_joins(customer: :program)
orders.where.not(programs: { number: excluded_numbers })
      .or(orders.where(programs: { number: nil }))
      .where(...)
```

The condition for `or` to work is that *the two relations must be structurally compatible*, so, both must include the joins and left_outer_joins you're using. That's the purpose of storing them in a local variable.